# How to check if the data already exists in the database?

Tags: php, mysql, json

How to check if the data($chassis, $pin) already exists in the database and if it does I want it to throw an error back saying "User exists".
I'm using json to display errors and right now using the below code the data gets inserted even if the chassis and pin already exists in the database.

```php
<?php
session_start();

require("config/config.php");
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
if (isset($_POST['user_submit']))
    $chassis = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['chassis']);
$pin           = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pin']);
$title         = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
$fname         = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
$lname         = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
$email         = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$mobile        = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mobile']);
$dob           = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dob']);
$anniversary   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['anniversary']);
$company       = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['company']);
$designation   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['designation']);
$home_business = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['home_business']);
$add1          = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['add1']);
$add2          = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['add2']);
$city          = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city']);
$state         = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['state']);
$pincode       = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pincode']);
$date          = date('y.m.d h:i:s A');

$hostname = '';
$database = '';
$username = '';
$password = '';

$conn = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
if (!$conn) {
    $json['error'] = "Unable to Connect server!" . mysql_error();
}
if (empty($json)) {
    mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database!" . mysql_error());
    $sql = mysql_query('SELECT chassis,pin FROM checking_chassis WHERE chassis="' . $chassis . '" && pin="' . $pin . '" ');

    if (mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1) {

        $sql1 = mysql_query('SELECT chassis,pin FROM taj_contact_info WHERE chassis="' . $chassis . '" && pin="' . $pin . '" ');
        if (mysql_num_rows($sql1) == 1) {
            $json['error'] = "User already exists";
            exit();
        } else {
            $query = 'INSERT INTO taj_contact_info (chassis,pin,title,fname,lname,email,mobile,dob,anniversary,company,designation,home_business,add1,add2,city,state,pincode,date_added) VALUES("' . $chassis . '","' . $pin . '","' . $title . '","' . $fname . '","' . $lname . '","' . $email . '","' . $mobile . '","' . $dob . '","' . $anniversary . '","' . $company . '","' . $designation . '","' . $home_business . '","' . $add1 . '","' . $add2 . '","' . $city . '","' . $state . '","' . $pincode . '","' . $date . '")';

            $sql1 = mysql_query($query);

            $message = "Thank you for registering. You can indulge in the fine dining experience with the Taj gift certificate, which will reach you within 30 days. Team Purple Club";

            $sms = "http://bulkpush.mytoday.com/BulkSms/SingleMsgApi?feedid=340479&UserName=&password=&sendername=PURPLE&To=" . $mobile . "&message=" . urlencode($message) . "";

            $work = file_get_contents($sms);

            $json['success'] = "Successfully inserted";
        }
    } else {
        $json['error1'] = "Please enter valid chassis number and pin";

    }

}

echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){

        $("#user_submit_form").submit(function(){
            var user_data = $("#user_submit_form").serialize();

                                var mobile = new Array();                                                            
                                                mobile = $('#mobile').val().split("");

                                                var pincode = new Array();                                                          
                                                pincode = $('#pincode').val().split("");

                                                if($('#chassis').val() =='')
                                                {                                              
                                                                                alert('Please enter chassis');
                                                }              
                                                else if ($('#pin').val() =='')
                                                {                                              
                                                                                alert('Please enter pin');
                                                }


                                                else        {

                                                                                $.ajax({
                                                                                type                                                            : "post",
                                                                                url                                                             : "validate_user.php",
                                                                                data                                                            : user_data,
                                                                                dataType                                                        : "json",
                                                                                success: function(json){

                                                                                                if(json.error)
                                                                                                {
                                                                                                                alert(json.error)
                                                                                                }
                                                                                                else if(json.error1)

                                                                                                {
                                                                                                                alert(json.error1)

                                                                                                }
                                                                                                else
                                                                                                {
                                                                                                                alert(json.success)
                                                                                                                /*location.reload();

                                                                                                                window.location="http://clps.cequitysolutions.com/taj/thankyou.php";*/

                                                                                                }
                                                                                }


                                                                                });


                                                                                }
        });                   

                });
      function validateEmail(email) 
                {
                                var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;                                                                                            
                                return re.test(email);
                }
</script>
```

Comment: Could be good if you do a SELECT query before insertion to check whether any user exists with the username or email, if the returning row count is more than 1, then you could throw an error else perform the insert query and show success message to user.

Comment: Where is the JavaScript?

Comment: hope the PHP indention /structure is better now, was not very readable :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you should create unique indexes for `chassis` and `pin`. Avoiding duplicates is exactly why unique indexes exists :

```sql
alter table taj_contact_info add unique index(chassis, pin)
```

Now you can run your insert query safely :

```php
$query = 'INSERT INTO taj_contact_info (chassis,pin,title,fname,lname,email,mobile,dob,anniversary,compa ...
```

and after that check if a record has been inserted :

```php
if (mysql_affected_rows()>0) {
  //success
} else {
   $json['error'] = "User already exists"
}
```

If `mysql_affected_rows` returns -1, the insert script has failed. That would happend if (I guess) chassis is not valid, like an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Make a unique index for both columns on the taj_contact_info table.

```
ALTER TABLE taj_contact_info ADD UNIQUE INDEX uniqueindex ( chassis,pin )
```

and after in php when you try to insert as normal, you will get a duplicate key error which you can handle in php...

```
$sql = "insert into taj_contact_info set chassis='1234', pin='12345',etc...";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    if (mysql_errno() == 1586) {
        echo "ID is already in the database, user exists";
    } else {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
} else {
    echo "All cool, user inserted.";
}
```

Comment: +1 for the unique index solution, but it is very riscy to base code on individual mysql error codes. 100 things can go wrong, and then you have to check for 100 different error codes. What if the errno is not 1586? Then the system will just `die`, without meaningfull information to the user. Thats why it is better, I my opinion, to check `mysql_affected_rows`.

Comment: If you use mysql_affected_rows() you will get that the user "exists" even if your sql query is wrong, or mysql server is down. The point of my answer is to provide a solution for your issue, not to describe error handling ways. Using the err 1586 you handle only the duplicate code as error, you are not obliged to put die() or treat all error codes .... it was just an example so you can debug.